# Как можно получить email пользователя при авторизации через facebook?

Tags: php

Как можно получить email пользователя при авторизации через facebook? 
На данный момент я смогла получить только "name" и "id".

Answer (score 1):

Eдинственный способ получить email пользователя это создать соответствующий запрос.

Тут подробнее
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

P.S К стати пользователь может быть зарегестрирован с помощью номерна телефона, в таком случае поле email будет пустым